# Changing to Python 64 bit version seems to have broken things

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, pytorch

I couldn't figure out why installing PyTorch was failing when using the exact procedure in the official "getting started" page. Then I found one little blurb deep in a forum that I should check that I had 64-bit python installed. Sure enough, I did not. So I uninstalled the 32-bit version and installed the 64-bit.

Now, when I type `python --version`, I get

```
bash: /c/Users/wesle/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python: Permission denied
```

Which is strange, because that's never where Python was installed in the first place. Kinda a funny place to look for it now.

**But**, typing `py --version`, which is a solution I found here does show the correct version.

Another thing that seems broken is Jupyter Lab. Now I get `bash: jupyter: command not found`.

Oh, here's a big one I just found: I can't run my scripts in PyCharm now. So Jupyter and my IDE are toast. I guess I've been needing to learn the command line a bit more...

All joking aside, I'm kinda afraid to do anything else at this point since apparently I screwed up pretty bad already.

Lifeline, please...

Oh and yes, my PATH variable is up-to-date with the new version.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my Python to 64bit from 32bit the other day and was also running into issues. What I had to do was delete out the folder of all the modules/packages I had installed previously and reinstall them. It seems the other packages were also 32bit and therefor would not work.

If you can find where you have the packages, try deleting them then installing new ones using pip as you did before.